# Неверное присваивание номера id к объекту в базе данных PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

В таблице базы данных допустим 10 объектов, я их удаляю через админ панель django. После удаления, я добавляю туда объект, после чего смотрю на таблицу бд и у этого обьекта `id == 11`, хотя должен быть `id == 1`.
 Как это исправить, чтобы отсчет всегда был от единицы?

Comment: id и должен быть 11, потому что следующее значение для id берется из sequence-а, а не +1 от id последней записи

Comment: ID (который первичный индекс и автоинкремент) решает задачу уникальной идентификации записи в течение всего времени жизни таблицы. Именно таблицы, а не записи - то, что запись удалена, не означает, что значение освободилось. Нужна нумерация - заведи для этого ещё одно поле.

Answer (score 0):

в консоли делаем для своего приложения (app)
`python manage.py sqlsequencereset app`

в выводе ищем свою таблицу (table), копируем

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"app_table"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "app_table";
```

идем в `psql`, `pgadmin4`, `dbshell` или куда вам удобнее, вставляем, выполняем. 
профит